# How can I put all network operations in single thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working with network so I have to use new thread.These my methods in `SmackClass`:

```
public void login(String username,String password) throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException {
        ConnectionConfiguration configuration=new ConnectionConfiguration("", 5222,"localhost");
        configuration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
        connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);
        connection.connect();
        connection.login(username,password);
        chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        chatManager.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
            public void chatCreated(final Chat chat, final boolean createdLocally) {
                chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendMessage(String to,String message) throws NotConnectedException, XMPPException {
         Chat chat=chatManager.createChat(to,messageListener);
         chat.sendMessage(message);
    }
```

I am calling above methods like this(in main class):

```
final SmackClass smack=new SmackClass();
        Thread thread=new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    smack.login("android","test");
                } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        try {
            smack.sendMessage("pidgin@localhost", "test");
        } catch (NotConnectedException | XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My application is giving `nullPointerException` for `smack.sendMessage` line because I am setting `chatManager` variable inside `login` method and  this method is running in another thread.I know if I put `smack.sendMessage` line to inside this thread it will work.But I don't want to do this.Because I will use `sendMessage` method in another main class method.How can I resolve this problem ? I guess I need to do all network operations in single thread (not ui thread) but how ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to implement a Queue. NetworkThread always look at queue if anything to process. Chat UI thread can put the command in to queue.

```
public class NetworkThread implements Runnable {

Queue<Command> queue;

public NetworkThread(Queue<Command> queue) throws IOException {
    this.queue = queue;

}

public void run() {

        while (true) {
            Command command = queue.poll()
            if(command != null){
               command.execute();
            }
        }
}
```

}

Command is a interface you can define to implement each network operation.

```
interface Command{

   public void execute();

}

class LoginCommand implements Command{

   public void execute(){
       //Do login operation 
   }

}
```

Now UI thread can push a Command Object in to queue, network thread will take care of executing it. Yo u may need to implement a message return mechanism in reverse direction as well.

Comment: Can you give full code for interface and LoginCommand ? I didn't understand where should I put these.http://prntscr.com/5lfgvl http://prntscr.com/5lfh08